# Java: regex - how do i get the first quote text

Tags: java, regex

As a beginner with **regex** i believe im about to ask something too simple but ill ask anyway hope it won't bother you helping me..

Lets say i have a text like **"hello 'cool1' word! 'cool2'"**
and i want to get the first quote's text (which is 'cool1' without the ')

what should be my pattern? and when using matcher, how do i guarantee it will remain the first quote and not the second?

(please suggest a solution only with regex.. )

Comment: [Great regular expression learning site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) with specifics for many languages such as [Java](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
'([^']*)'
```

Use as follows: [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/02TJx)

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'([^']*)'");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Or this if you know that there are no new-line characters in your quoted string:

```
'(.*?)'
```

---

> when using matcher, how do i guarantee it will remain the first quote and not the second?

It will find the first quoted string first because it starts seaching from left to right. If you ask it for the next match it will give you the second quoted string.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `""` around your string? Is that for the Java string or?

Comment: @DavidB: Yes, I was assuming that it's written as a Java string literal.

Comment: IMO I would remove them simply so a newbie doesn't throw it into Java and wonder why his regex isn't matching / his IDE is throwing illegal escapes at him.

Comment: @DavidB: Updated to include both versions.

Comment: Mark thank you very much, i have a question: in general, lets say i had 2 patterns, the one you wrote and another one which is the same idea but with " instead of ' and i wanted to use OR between the two, how could i know what is the founded group between the two? in other words, how can i know after using find() which of the groups was found?

Comment: @Popokoko: It would be easier to use a backreference `\1` to match the closing quote. This would be better than an alternation because then you'd only have one group, so there'd be no problem.

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your effort to explain but i either i dont understand or i should sharp it a bit: i asked a question in general, lets say u have "(pattern1)|(pattern2)" how can i get the result from find() ? should i do ""(pattern1)|(pattern2)\1" ? (assuming i don't know if the first group is the result or the second one..)

Comment: Much easier just to put the parentheses around the entire expresison: `"(pattern1|pattern2)"`.

Comment: Hmm, but what happens if pattern 1 is complicated like what u just gave me.. that will create another inner group, same for pattern 2, meanning ill have ( (..) | (..) ) and that way i can't determine how should i use groups to get my result..

Comment: @Popokoko: I don't know... can you come up with a specific example? I'm fairly sure that for most situations there will be a way to write it without needing nested capturing groups. I've written hundreds of regular expressions and I can't think of an example where I needed to do what you are describing.

Comment: (First, thanks for the continued assistance) I'll take ur code as example: "'([^']*)'|"([^']*)"" the idea is to support both quote types " and '.. assuming i use groups, i fail to get my result..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find first quote's text without the `'` you can/should use Lookahead and Lookbehind mechanism like

```
(?<=').*?(?=')
```

for example

```
System.out.println("hello 'cool1' word! 'cool2'".replaceFirst("(?<=').*?(?=')", "ABC"));
//out -> hello 'ABC' word! 'cool2'
```

[more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string on quotes and get the second piece (which will be between the first and second quotes).

If you insist on regex, try this:

```
/^.*?'(.*?)'/
```

Make sure it's set to multiline, unless you know you'll never have newlines in your input. Then, get the subpattern from the result and that will be your string.

To support double quotes too:

```
/^.*?(['"])(.*?)\1/
```

Then get subpattern 2.