# How to get the words within the first single quote in r using regex?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

For example, I have two strings:

```
stringA = "'contentX' is not one of ['Illumina NovaSeq 6000', 'Other', 'Ion Torrent PGM', 'Illumina HiSeq X Ten', 'Illumina HiSeq 4000', 'Illumina NextSeq', 'Complete Genomics', 'Illumina Genome Analyzer II']"
```

I am not familiar how to do regex and stuck to extract words within the first single quotes.

Expected

```
## do regex here
gsub("'(.*)'", "\\1", stringA) # not working

> "contentX"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: regex - how do i get the first quote text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769813/java-regex-how-do-i-get-the-first-quote-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example your pattern would be:

```
gsub("^'(.*?)'.*", "\\1", stringA)
```

https://regex101.com/r/bs3lwJ/1

First we assert we're at the beginning of the string and that the following character is a single quote with `^'`. Then we capture everything up until the next single quote in group 1, using `(.*?)'`.

Note that we need the `?` in `.*?` otherwise `.*` will be "greedy" and match all the way through to the last occurrence of a single quote, rather then the next single quote.